# Parse VMware REST API response

Tags: bash, awk, vmware

I'm trying to parse a json response from a REST API call. My awk is not strong.  This is a bash shell script, and I use curl to get the response and write it to a file.  My problem is solely trying to cut the response up into useful parts.

The response is all run together on one line and looks like this:

```
{
    "value": {
        "summary": "Patch for VMware vCenter Server Appliance 6.5.0",
        "install_time": "2017-03-22T22:43:25 UTC",
        "product": "VMware vCenter Server Appliance",
        "build": "5178943",
        "releasedate": "March 14, 2017",
        "type": "vCenter Server with an external Platform Services Controller",
        "version": "6.5.0.5300"
    }
}
```

I'm interested in simply writing the type, version, and product strings into a log file.  Ideally on 3 lines, but I really don't care; I simply need to be able to identify the build etc at the time this backup script ran, so if I need to rebuild & restore I can make sure I have a compatible build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Rest API gives you JSON format, it's best suited for a JSON parser like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) :

```
curl -s '/rest/endpoint' | jq -r '.value | .type,.version,.product' > config.txt
```

Comment: That is awesome. I'm not 100% keen on having to add an additional component to make it work, but hopefully some appropriate comments in the logs should direct people to being able to recreate in the future if needed. If there's a reasonable way to do this with built-in tools (awk cut etc) then I'm keen to hear about them too.